# tidyverse and dplyr - package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I execute:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

and get back:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘dplyr’
```

then I run:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

and it installs everything successfully.

but `library(tidyverse)` still produces the same error

Comment: Reinstall tidy verse?

Comment: @NelsonGon, thank you, it helped.